# How to save each forloop output into separated file name not in a single file name?

Tags: python-3.7

I want to save each output of "forloop" into different text file, not in a single text file. Like for example. First loop output will be in Device1_Output01.txt, Second loop output
will be in Device2_Output02.txt, Device3_Output03.txt, etc. Please help me I'm a beginner. Appreciate your help in advance. Thank you.

```
import paramiko
import time
import sys


c = open("Command_List.txt", "r")
command_list = c.read().split("\n")    /*Create a List from Command_List file */

        
d = open("Device_List.txt", "r")
nodes = d.read().split("\n")           /*Create a List from Device_List file */                  



port = 22
username = "user"
password = "password"

for ip in nodes:              /*Loop each ip in hosts list */                    
    print("Login to:", ip)
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(ip, port, username, password)
    comm = ssh.invoke_shell()

    for command in command_list:           /*Loop each commmand in command_list    
        comm.send(' %s \n' %command)
        time.sleep(.5)
        output = comm.recv(9999)
        output = output.decode('ascii').split(',')   /*Convert string to List without any change*/

        restorepoint = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open('HWOutput.txt', "a")   /*All output will be appended here. How will I save each forloop output into different filenames?.*/
        print(''.join(output))
        sys.stdout = restorepoint

ssh.close()
```

Comment: when you say output do you mean text other than your print statements?

Comment: Yes, I mean text.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace `sys.stdout` with an actual open file at the start of the loop, then close the file and revert back to initial `stdout` at the end.

```py
for ip in nodes:
    if not ip.strip(): continue
    with open(ip + ".ssh-log.txt","wt") as sshlog:
        sys.stdout = sshlog
        print("Login to:", ip)
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(ip, port, username, password)
        comm = ssh.invoke_shell()
        for command in command_list:
            comm.send(' %s \n' %command)
            time.sleep(.5)
            output = comm.recv(9999)
            output = output.decode('ascii').split(',')
            print(''.join(output))
    sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__

ssh.close()
```

Comment: Hi alexpdev, It works. Thank you. Appreciate much. :)

Comment: @haggai45 Try it now

Comment: hi @alexpdev, Yeah I already tried your script, it works. My problem is after reading all ip addresses in Device_List.txt 
it shows this error "socket.gaierror: [Errno 8] Name does not resolve."
Anyways, I just use crontab just to get the desired output. thank you. :)

crontab:

*/5 * * * * python3.7 ~/HW_forloop_01_170522.py --> (I put your script here)
*/6 * * * * python3.7 ~/HWdf_02_170522.py
*/7 * * * * python3.7 ~/HW_AttachToEmail_03_170522.py

Comment: @haggai45  I edited my answer though...  the for loop now will only consider lines that are not empty... If you tried it and it still isn't working, then it is probably an error thrown by the `paramiko` .

Comment: thanks for your reply. using your updated script:

File "HW_forloop_01_170522.py", line 21
    for ip in nodes if ip.strip():
 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @haggai45  My bad... try it now.  Sorry

Comment: it works. yehey! :)  thank you so much for your help. appreciate much. :)

Comment: sure... glad i could help